# Changing an objects axis

Tags: objects

Sorry this is a noob question but I'm just stuck. So I am trying to reorient the local axis of an object after I change it's global position. So say there is a cube and I rotate it on it's z axis 45° now it's x and y are pointing off all crazy. I want to change the local axis to line up with the global axis again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your cube in *Object Mode* and apply the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*

[image: Apply Rotation]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood, but you can change the object orientation on the **Transformation Orientation** option at the **3D View** window menu.

[image]

**Note:** The menu is usually bellow of the 3D View window.